# Fetching HDFS Path In a List Dynamically Using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one scenario where I need to collect a list of filepaths based on the number of hours in the current day folder.

I.e., I have the following path:

```
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=19
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=20
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=21
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=22
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=23
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=00
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=01
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=02
```

So here I will hardcode the path till '/user/hdfs/test/'. My code will append the partition_date using the date function and will take the current date.

Let's say the current timestamp is 2022-09-21 19:00
So here the date will be 2022-09-21 and the value of an hour will be 19.

I will pass the number of hours value from the spark submit command, so if this value is 2, the code will fetch the path of the last 2 hours . Let's say the current time is 2022-09-21 19:00
Then I need to fetch the paths.

```
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=19, 
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=18
```

Similarly, if hours 3, the need to fetch

```
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=19, 
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=18 ,
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=17.
```

At 00, 01,etc. hrs (at 12 am or after 12 am ) the current date will change to the next day's date, so if I pass the number of hours 2, it should fetch the previous hour from the previous date.

so the path will be :

```
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=00,
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=23,
```

If I pass the number of hours at 3 at 1 am  hours ,

So basically, it should take

```
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=01   
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=00 
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=23
```

I am trying the below code locally, but here I need to hardcode the number of hours and accordingly I am generating the path.

```
var currentHour=0
var prevHour=
var flag = 0
var currpath = ""
var prevpath = ""
var CurrentDate = java.time.LocalDate.now
var PreviousDate=java.time.LocalDate.now.minusDays(1)

val now = Calendar.getInstance()
if ( now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 1) {
 currentHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
 prevHour = "23".toInt
flag=0
}
else {
 currentHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
 prevHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 1
flag=1
}
val hdfsConf = new Configuration();

val path = "/user/hdfs/test/"

if(flag==0) {
 currpath =
  (path + "partition_date=" + CurrentDate + "/" + "hour=" + currentHour + "/")
 prevpath =
  (path + "partition_date=" + PreviousDate + "/" + "hour=" + prevHour + "/")
}
else{
 currpath =
  (path + "partition_date=" + CurrentDate + "/" + "hour=" + currentHour + "/")
 prevpath =
  (path + "partition_date=" + CurrentDate + "/" + "hour=" + prevHour + "/")
}
```

Can someone please help me?

How to make it generic so I can pass the number of hours dynamically and, accordingly, it can take the paths in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
val currentTs = java.time.LocalDateTime.now
val hours = 3
val paths = (0 until hours)
  .map(h => currentTs.minusHours(h))
  .map(ts => s"/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=${ts.toLocalDate}/hour=${ts.getHour}")
paths.foreach(println)

/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=14
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=13
/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=12
```

Comment: Thanks @Kombajn zbożowy.

It's Working fine  for Current day.          

But If I execute the same code at 12 AM  Night,           

so the LocalDateTime will change to 2022-09-22 and hour will be '00'.         

In that case I need to fetch.           


/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-22/hour=00                



/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=23                  




/user/hdfs/test/partition_date=2022-09-21/hour=22               



Can You Suggest Please.

Comment: It will work fine, just try it out...

Comment: Sure Thanks a lot @Kombajn zbożowy.

let me try it. I will Update here.

Comment: Thanks @Komba

It worked ..I accepted the answer.Kindly suggest me in one more scenario plz. I have added new question here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821158/loading-hdfs-files-in-a-spark-dataframe-using-loop?noredirect=1#comment130361685_73821158